# Facebook Assembly Reference Issue With Sample Site

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I cannot get the sample (CSASPNETFacebookApp) included with the Facebook C# SDK samples to run. When I try to run it I get the following error:

```
CS0012: The type 'Facebook.FacebookClient' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Facebook, Version=5.0.26.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=58cb4f2111d1e6de'.
```

So I added the following into my web.config:

```
  <add assembly="Facebook, Version=5.0.26.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=58cb4f2111d1e6de"/>
```

After this  I tried to I run it and I get:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Facebook, Version=5.0.26.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=58cb4f2111d1e6de' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have my Facebook Application set up and the parameters inputted in my Web.config.  I have manually added a reference to Facebook.Web.dll via Solution Explorer in Visual Studio, but no love.

Is there something else I should be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the Facebook.dll file as well.